# How to make namespace alias available after initial compile time?

Tags: clojure

I'm working on a Clojure application that needs to be able to read Clojure code from the shell command line.  The application has a `-main` function that reads a string passed on the command line containing a single Clojure form, and passes this string to the Clojure function `load-string`, which parses the string and executes the code.  This runs successfully using both `lein run` and using an uberjar.

I've found that the code passed at the command line can include fully-qualified namespace names if the namespaces were `required` at the top of the file containing `-main`.  For example, if the source file begins with

```
(ns popco.core.popco
  (:require [popco.core.reporters :as rpt]))
```

then the string I pass on the command line can reference my function `ticker` by `popco.core.reporters/ticker`.  However, I can't use the alias `rpt`.  If I refer to `ticker` by `rpt/ticker`, I get an exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: rpt`.

I'm guessing that this is because the aliases are only available at compile time, and only one compile time.  Since the time at which `load-file` compiles the string of code is after the time at which compilation of the source file has been completed, `rpt` is no longer available as an alias.

A solution that allows me to use namespace aliases is to duplicate the `require`s at the top of the file (which I want for use when running in the repl) within `-main`.  However, there are several namespaces that I might need to include, and duplicating code is undesirable, of course.

Is there another solution?  Some way to make aliases defined once, available both when runnning in the repl and when running code from the command line?

(EDIT: The analysis in terms of time of compilation above can't quite be correct--or maybe I don't understand Clojure compilation.  (Well, in fact I don't understand Clojure compilation!)  The solution mentioned in two paragraphs above works using a `require` statement in the original source code inside `-main`, not only with a string passed to `load-file`.  So that `require` is getting compiled when `-main` is compiled, I suppose, which would be during the same pass as the top of the source file, I assume.  Yet somehow code inside `-main` is in scope of the alias from the top of the file if the code was typed into the definition of `-main`, but not if it's brought in via `load-file`.  Yet what's brought in via `load-file` is in the scope of the alias when `(require '[popco.core.reporters :as rpt])` is literally in the source code for `-main`.  Why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alias` function, which is the mechanism require uses to create namespace aliases via the `:as` key, mutates the *current* namespace. That is, the namespace that is current at the time `alias` runs.

This is why `require` embedded into your definition of `-main` creates the alias in the way you expect: it is mutating your runtime namespace to include the given alias. Emphatically, this does not necessarily alter the `popco.core.popco` namespace! In fact, that is unlikely to be the working namespace at runtime, when `-main` is invoked (it would be at *compile* time, and thus would, as in the `ns` macro, mutate the ns being defined).

The key here is to realize that the `ns` at runtime is not always the `ns` which defined your `-main` function, and if you want to mutate the evaluation environment at runtime, you need to either switch to the namespace you are mutating, or mutate the namespace you are in.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation.  Very interesting, and helpful.